# Combining column totals of different tables into one

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

I have multiple tables: A, B, C, and D.

Each of them have different numbers of columns and rows. But each of them have one column for ONLY today’s date and one column for a specific value (for each row that is).

Now I want to calculate the total of the column for each table (A, B, C, and D) and each total (4 different totals in this case) should be inserted into a new table into separate columns.

In this final table I should also have the date in the first column.

So the final table should have 1 row and 5 columns (1 for today’s date and 4 for the totals)

I tried solving this with a LEFT JOIN on the date. But the values don’t add up.

Could you please help me out. I’m fairly new to SAS/SQL.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your current query would also be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have access to a computer. I’m on my cell phone as I’m travelling right now.

Comment: @user361695 There's no rush; just when you have a chance.

Comment: Just trying to figure out the logic. But is it a prerequisite to have the same number of rows when doing a JOIN of any kind?

Comment: No. If it were, databases would be of extremely limited usefulness

Comment: MySQL does not implement FULL OUTER JOIN, and it seems you'll need it, in cases the tables do not include values for the same dates. It's doable, though but a bit cumbersome.

Comment: MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8.x?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do something like this:

```
select curdate() as today,
       (select sum(a.value) from a where a.datecol = curdate()) as a,
       (select sum(b.value) from b where b.datecol = curdate()) as b,
       (select sum(c.value) from c where c.datecol = curdate()) as c,
       (select sum(d.value) from d where d.datecol = curdate()) as d
```

EDIT:

If there is only current data in all the tables, then the `where` clause is not needed:

```
select curdate() as today,
       (select sum(a.value) from a) as a,
       (select sum(b.value) from b) as b,
       (select sum(c.value) from c) as c,
       (select sum(d.value) from d) as d
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’ll try this. I’ll provide with a dataset soon as well. However, is it necessary to have the WHERE statement? The tables only have data for today’s date. So the entire date column only contains value matching today’s date.

Answer (score 0):

You need `FULL OUTER JOIN`s to deal with cases when tables include non-matching dates. Since MySQL does not implement them you'll need to combine `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` to simulate them.

In MySQL 8.x you can do:

```
with
l (dt, a, b) as (
  select a.dt, a.val, b.val from a left join b on b.dt = a.dt
  union
  select b.dt, a.val, b.val from a right join b on b.dt = a.dt
),
r (dt, c, d) as (
  select c.dt, c.val, d.val from c left join d on c.dt = d.dt
  union
  select d.dt, c.val, d.val from c right join d on c.dt = d.dt
)
select l.dt, l.a, l.b, r.c, r.d from l left join r on r.dt = l.dt
union
select r.dt, l.a, l.b, r.c, r.d from l right join r on r.dt = l.dt
```

Result:

```
dt          a       b       c       d     
----------  ------  ------  ------  ------
2019-09-15  60      61      62      63    
2019-09-16  140     null    null    null
2019-09-17  null    141     null    null
2019-09-18  null    null    142     null
2019-09-19  null    null    null    143
```

For reference, the data script to test it is:

```
create table a (dt date, val int);
create table b (dt date, val int);
create table c (dt date, val int);
create table d (dt date, val int);

insert into a (dt, val) values ('2019-09-15', 60), ('2019-09-16', 140);
insert into b (dt, val) values ('2019-09-15', 61), ('2019-09-17', 141);
insert into c (dt, val) values ('2019-09-15', 62), ('2019-09-18', 142);
insert into d (dt, val) values ('2019-09-15', 63), ('2019-09-19', 143);
```

In this scenario, all tables have data for `2019-09-15` but not for the other dates. The query combines them successfully, nevertheless.

As a side note, if `FULL OUTER JOIN` were implemented the query would be way shorter. For example in PostgreSQL you would write:

```
select coalesce(a.dt, b.dt, c.dt, d.dt), a.val, b.val, c.val, d.val
from a
full outer join b on b.dt = a.dt
full outer join c on c.dt = coalesce(a.dt, b.dt)
full outer join d on d.dt = coalesce(a.dt, b.dt, c.dt)
```

Comment: Note that if using SAS you would need to use PASS THROUGH SQL to have this work correctly.